# How to keep alive connection using VNC

Tags: raspbian, vnc, debian

I’m want to run a python script and I need it working 24/7. I have a Raspberry Pi 4 (it’s running the last version of raspbian) and I connect it using VNC but after a few times when I try to connect to my Raspberry Pi to see what’s going on is like the VNC reconnects me and kills the old session (that’s what I think) or maybe just disappear.

- I already changed idletimeout to 0 and also try to use teamviever but is the same.
- I think if I connect the Raspberry Pi to HDMI to any screen and then connect via VNC the problem is solved, but I want to know if exists another solution.

Comment: If you need to run continuously why are you using VNC?

Comment: I m expressed wrong, I run the python script but then one time per hour i need to check if it s running ok, so i need to keep the session

Comment: Use an ssh connection and run the script e.g. in a `screen`. Then you can log off without killing the script and later reconnect via ssh and resume the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a python script (or indeed any script) continuously start it running in the background or use tmux.